# PostgreSQL 12.9: Finding the count of other players that participated in the same activity

Tags: postgresql

Version *PostgreSQL 12.9*

I have the following table that catalogs a list of activities played by a playerid, and another table that serves as the map for the players information along with a clan id, what I want to do is count the number of players that participated in the same instance id, that have the same clan id.
My table structure is as follows:

Activities Table

```sql
CREATE TABLE "public"."activities" (
  "playerdestinyid" int8 NOT NULL,
  "instanceid" int8 NOT NULL,
  "timestamp" timestamptz(6) NOT NULL);
```

Players Table

```sql
CREATE TABLE "public"."players" (
  "destinyid" int8 NOT NULL,
  "name" varchar(255) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" NOT NULL,
  "clanid" int8 NOT NULL,
  "characterids" jsonb NOT NULL);
```

Edit 1:
First attempted query

```sql
SELECT
    ROUND(
        SUM (
            ( ( activities.kills * activities.killsdeathsratio ) * 100 ) * ( SELECT COUNT ( * ) * 1.05 FROM "activities" INNER JOIN "players" ON ( "playerdestinyid" = "destinyid" ) GROUP BY "instanceid", "clanid" ) 
        )) AS "Score",
        players.clanid AS "clanId",
        ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( ORDER BY SUM ( ( activities.kills * activities.killsdeathsratio ) * 100 ) DESC ) AS POSITION,
        COUNT ( players.clanid ) AS "gamesplayed" 
    FROM
        activities
        INNER JOIN players ON activities.playerdestinyid = players.destinyid
    WHERE
        TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2022-03-15 17:00:00+00' 
        AND now( ) 
    GROUP BY
        players.clanid
ORDER BY
    SUM ( ( activities.kills * activities.killsdeathsratio ) * 100 ) DESC
```

The error returned:

```
> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Edit 2:
I got what the query re-written using the CTE as suggested, but it's still giving me the  `ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` response though.

```sql
WITH clan_multi AS ( SELECT (COUNT ( * ) * 1.05) as multiplier FROM "activities" INNER JOIN "players" ON ( "playerdestinyid" = "destinyid" ) GROUP BY "instanceid", "clanid" ) 
SELECT
ROUND( SUM ( ( activities.kills * activities.killsdeathsratio ) * 100 ) ) AS "Score",
players.clanid AS "clanId",
(SELECT multiplier from clan_multi),
ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( ORDER BY SUM ( ( activities.kills * activities.killsdeathsratio ) * 100 ) DESC ) AS POSITION,
COUNT ( players.clanid ) AS "gamesplayed" 
FROM
    activities
    INNER JOIN players ON activities.playerdestinyid = players.destinyid 
    INNER JOIN clan_multi ON activities.instanceid = instanceid AND players.clanid = clanId
WHERE
    TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2022-03-15 17:00:00+00' 
    AND now( ) 
GROUP BY
    players.clanid 
ORDER BY
    SUM ( ( activities.kills * activities.killsdeathsratio ) * 100 ) DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  "instanceid",
  "clanid",
  count(*)
FROM "activities"
INNER JOIN "players" ON ("playerdestinyid" = "destinyid")
GROUP BY
  "instanceid",
  "clanid"
```

Comment: I thought I could just add as a sub query but I suppose it has to be more complicated than that, my goal with this is to have a multiplier applied when players run activities with people from their own clanid, your answer worked well for getting the count, but I am having a hard time incorporating it into my query. I'm out of length so I will add the query to the OP.

Comment: I would recommend using a CTE (the `WITH` keyword) if you want to use the counts. You can then `JOIN` this CTE using the `clanid` from the player (and probably the `instanceid` from some other table).

Comment: Tried it, still giving a similar error. See OP Edit 2.

Comment: Replace `(SELECT multiplier FROM clan_multi)` by `clan_multi.multiplier`. The `SELECT multiplier ...` returns multiple rows and therefore can not be used as a sub-select.

Comment: I think that is what I am looking for, going to have to rethink my strategy because the number coming back is way higher than I expected. Thank you for your assistance!